# Flutter UI freezez while rendring a large list of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

What would be the proper way to render a huge number of widgets in a list without blocking UI? I have almost 700+ tags in firebase and I am trying to display them on a page using `StreamBuilder` like this:

```
class _TagsManagementPageState extends State<TagsManagementPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Search Tags"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseManager.firebaseDatabase().ref("search_tags").onValue,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                if (!snap.hasError && snap.hasData) {
                  DataSnapshot snapshot = snap.data.snapshot;
                  if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    List tagsList = Map.from(snapshot.val()).values.toList()
                      ..sort((a, b) {
                        var tagA = a["title"] ?? "";
                        var tagB = b["title"] ?? "";
                        return tagA.toLowerCase().compareTo(tagB.toLowerCase());
                      });
                    return Wrap(
                      spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                      runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                      children: tagsList
                          .map((searchTag) => _TagItem(searchTag))
                          .toList(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "No Tag Available...!",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TagItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final searchTag;

  final delRef = FirebaseManager.firebaseDatabase().ref("search_tags");

  _TagItem(this.searchTag);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InputChip(
      elevation: 3,
      deleteIconColor: Colors.red,
      label: Text(searchTag['title'] ?? "null"),
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine till loading from firebase but after that UI freezes for a while and then displays content on screen? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try pagination for large amount of data, which will download data in small chunks. https://blog.solutelabs.com/paginate-your-data-in-flutter-7744995febd1

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your sorting algorithm. You could try it without sorting first to see if that's the problem. If so you should take it out of your build method, put it into an async method and display a progress indicator while it's computing.

Comment: I've a list with 1000 items and it's not blockingthe UI when rendering, so I doub't that it's the amount of items...